# Express dev environment error: Failed to lookup view "pages/index" in views directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm getting this error both in the browser and on the terminal while trying to access my development environment:

> Error: Failed to lookup view "pages/index" in views directory "/home/juan/dev/my-project/lib/views"
> at Function.render
> (/home/juan/dev/my-project/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:583:17)
> at ServerResponse.render
> (/home/juan/dev/my-project/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1017:7)
> at file:///home/juan/dev/my-project/lib/index.js:15:31 at Layer.handle
> [as handle_request]
> (/home/juan/dev/my-project/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
> at next
> (/home/juan/dev/my-project/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
> at Route.dispatch
> (/home/juan/dev/my-project/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
> (/home/juan/dev/my-project/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
> at
> /home/juan/dev/my-project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
> at Function.process_params
> (/home/juan/dev/my-project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:341:12)
> at next
> (/home/juan/dev/my-project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)

`/home/juan/dev/my-project/lib/index.js`:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import {engine} from 'express-handlebars';

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const dirname = path.join(path.resolve(), 'lib');

let app = express();
app.engine('handlebars', engine({defaultlayout: 'index', extname: '.hbs'}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(dirname, 'views')));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('views', path.join(dirname, 'views'));
app
  .get('/', (req, res) => res.render('pages/index'))
  .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`));
```

Does anyone know what's happening?
Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: _"Does anyone know what's happening?"_ The file `/home/juan/dev/my-project/lib/views/pages/index.hbs` doesn't exist.

Comment: The paths `/home/juan/dev/my-project/lib/views/pages/index.hbs` and `/home/juan/dev/on-duty/lib/views/pages/index.hbs` are different.

Comment: No, they aren't.
I manually changed the name of the directory in my reply because I didn't want it to be public. Obviously, I failed ;)

Comment: `defaultlayout` should be `defaultLayout`, but it's probably unrelated.

Comment: @jabaa Changed to `defaultLayout`. It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register the engine under the same name you use for `extname`:

```
app.engine('.hbs', engine({ defaultlayout: 'index', extname: '.hbs' }));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
```

Otherwise, you'll get strange behavior.